# Infinite loop in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I've 672 files in local directory, filenames are like: `boutique-*_20160116hh0000.csv`, `general-tgbt_1_20160116hh0000.csv`, where hh - hours' number and (for instance, `boutique-a13_15_20160116060000.csv`, `boutique-a16_18_20160116070000.csv`, `boutique-a05_7_20160116190000.csv` and so on).

I run the following command in bash:

```
(for i in `ls -1 | sort`; do cat $i | while read line; do echo "${i%%_2016*}," $line; done ; done;) > c.csv
```

And it leads to infinite loop, file `c.csv` grows in size.

Whats the reason?

I believe that my `c.csv` file is also falling into result of

```
`ls -1 | sort`
```

But is this behaviour correct?

After getting the first comment I try another test - keep only 4 files instead of 672 (boutique-a05_7_20160116220000.csv, boutique-a16_18_20160116020000.csv, general-tgbt_1_20160116170000.csv, wago-pfc-750-815_99_20160116020000.csv) and my command works fine.

Thanks

Comment: `( commands here not run until at least ) > output_here_is_opened`

Comment: You seem to have created two accounts. Please see [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) for help on merging them.

Comment: Also, what exactly are you trying to do? What output are you expecting? You have chosen a very complicated way to do something that, if I understand correctly, is very simple. Please [edit] your question and explain what your final objective is, not just the command you used to achieve it.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed I want to put prefix from filename to each line of the file, merge that content in one big file (in sorted order). Although I'm curious about more simple ways always, the first reason of my question - what is the proper (maybe defined in any standard) way for bash to execute these command? Should my c.csv be also in the list from ls?

Comment: mikeserv, Could you please clarify is behaviour you mentioned specified in any standard (or official documentation)? I'm confused that when I kept only 4 files instead of 672 (boutique-a05_7_20160116220000.csv, boutique-a16_18_20160116020000.csv, general-tgbt_1_20160116170000.csv, wago-pfc-750-815_99_20160116020000.csv) my command works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to put the result elsewhere. The `ls` output is already sorted, but you don't need  that anyway. Shorten your script to:

```
for i in *.csv ; do
    while read line ; do
        echo "${i%%_2016*}," $line
    done <$i
done >/tmp/c.csv
```